# There is a $k$-point in every non-empty open subset of finite-type scheme $X$ over $k$

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a finite-type scheme over some field $k$, apparently if $k$ is algebraically closed then for every non-empty open set $U \subset X$, there is a $k$-point in $U$. According to class, this is equivalent to showing that there is a point in $U$ whose residual field is $k$.

I have found a simple proof which does not suppose $k$ to be algebraically closed, so it must be false. Could somebody please pinpoint the mistake?

Let $U \subset X$ a non-empty subset. Since $U$ can be covered with open affine sets, it is enough to find such a point $x \in V\subset U$, with $V$ affine non-empty.

Let $V = \text{Spec}A$, where $A$ is a finite-type $k$-algebra since $X$ is a finite-type scheme over $k$.
So $A \cong k[X_1,\cdots,X_n]/I$ for some integer $n$ and ideal $I$. Here, $A \neq 0$ since $V$ is non-empty.

Let $m=(X_1,\cdots,X_n) \in A$. The residual field of $m$ is $A_m/m = k$, so $m=x$ concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that $m$ contains $I$? It may not, as shown by the example $\Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$. Instead, the correct strategy here is to say that there exists a maximal ideal of $A$ (equivalent to a maximal ideal of $k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ containing $I$), as every nonzero unital ring contains a maximal ideal.